# How do I move an app out of a folder on iOS 8? (e.g. newspaper out of "newsstand")

Tags: ios, newsstand

The news app I use most frequently is buried in Home->News->Newsstand.
How can I move this app up to my first main page of apps?

Here I mean the New York Times app, which I want on my home screen. I've tried holding the NyTimes app until it wiggles, but it won't move out of the Newsstand (violating my expectations of the ability to move anything shaped like an app anywhere I want).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe say what version of iOS you are using?

Newsstand is not a normal folder.  You put items into it by subscribing to them.  And remove them by un-subscribing.  You can move Newsstand to the top level, though, in the same way as you move other icons (see the documentation).  One way is to use iTunes, switch things around there, then sync.  Another way involves holding your finger on the icon until it starts wiggling, then drag it.

Comment: @Bryce Perhaps this isn't the answer you're looking for, but alas even according to the NYTimes FAQ, it's true. [You can't move the NYTimes app out of the Newsstand folder.](http://www.nytimes.com/content/help/mobile/iphone/iphone/iphone.html#iphone-move-app)

Comment: With the newer version of iOS, you now *can* move the NYTimes app out of the Newsstand folder.